# How to avoid stack overflow when using scalaz's free monad?

Tags: scala, scalaz, free-monad

I had previously thought that part of the goal of the implementation was to avoid this very problem, so maybe I'm doing something obviously dumb?

Here is some code:

```
    // Stack overflow
import scalaz._

sealed trait Command[T]
case class Wait(ms: Long) extends Command[Unit]

case object Evaluator extends (Command ~> Id.Id) {
  override def apply[T](cmd: Command[T]) = cmd match {
    case Wait(t)  => Thread.sleep(t)
  }
}

object Api {
  def sleep(ms: Long): Free.FreeC[Command, Unit] = Free.liftFC(Wait(ms))
}

val sleep: Free.FreeC[Command, Unit] =
  Api.sleep(1).flatMap { _ => sleep }

Free.runFC(sleep)(Evaluator)
```

Note: I realize this is silly :) In practice, my command class has many commands, and I have a command which does this same loop...basically, poll some state, if true abort, if false, keep waiting.

I want to avoid the stack overflow that this causes... I THOUGHT this was already trampolined, but I guess I need to manually do it again? Is there a clean way to do it within the free monad way of thinking?

Update:

Thinking further on this, I think the issue isn't the sleep Free Monad but rather the Id.Id monad taht we bind into on evaluation... so I tried something like:

```
case object Evaluator2 extends (Command ~> ({ type t[x] = Free[Id.Id, x] })#t) {
  override def apply[T](cmd: Command[T]) = cmd match {
    case Wait(t)  => Thread.sleep(t); Free.liftF[Id.Id, Unit](())
  }
}

Free.runFC[Command, ({ type t[x] = Free[Id.Id, x] })#t, Unit](sleep)(Evaluator2)(Free.freeMonad[Id.Id])
```

But the problem with this is that it will only evaluate one step. Ideally I would like runFC to block until some condition is satisfied (or in this case, to loop forever until I kill it, but without a stack overflow)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Id` monad is not trampolined. You end up in an infinite mutual recursion between the `bind` method for the `Id` monad and the `foldMap` method for the free monad. Use `Trampoline` or `Task` instead of `Id`.

Answer (score 2):

Since @Apocalisp's answer, there has been addition of [`BindRec`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.3.0-M7/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/BindRec.scala) typeclass and [`foldMapRec`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.3.0-M7/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Free.scala#L229) method that can be used for stack-safe evaluation directly to `Id` (or any other "tail-recursive" monad). For details, read [Stack Safety for Free](http://functorial.com/stack-safety-for-free/index.pdf).